# How can I display pandas DataFrame into Django template?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a `pandas` DataFrame and I want to show this DataFrame into my `Django` template. But every time the code compiles successfully without showing any table in my `Django` web app. What am I missing here? My DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

and my html looks like:

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="card" style="width: auto;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="h3">Total match data and Profit Mergin</h3>
                    <br>
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Total Contest</th>
                            <th>Total Entry Amount</th>
                            <th>Total Seat</th>
                            <th>Total Winning Amount</th>
                            <th>Total Team Capacity</th>
                            <th>Profit Mergin</th>

                        {% for value in final_data.iterrows %}
                            
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ value.0 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ value.1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ value.2 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ value.3 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ value.4 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ value.5 }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried `final_data.iterrows` but still got the same result. What should I do now?

Comment: Please include how your python script is set up. Is the `final_data` provided to the template?

Comment: This is probably not a solution you are looking for but there is something like https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: @ClayWahlstrom this is how i provided final_data to my template:

final_df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
        # final_df = final_df.to_html()

        return render(request, 'dashboard/conversion.html', {'conversion': conversion, 'sdate': sdate, 'edate': edate, 'final_data': final_df})
    else:
        return render(request, 'dashboard/conversion.html')

hope this helps you to understand my problem.

Comment: I think you are missing a second return value, because `iterrows` return a tuple. Try with `{% for index, value in final_data.iterrows %}`

Answer (score 11):

This a basic html table that shows a pandas dataframe in a django template:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for col in df.columns %}
      <td>
        {{col}}
      </td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
    {% for index, row in df.iterrows %}
      <tr>
        {% for cell in row %}
          <td>
            {{cell}}
          </td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This one is not showing the index, so if you want to render it, you could pass `df.reset_index()` to the template.

Comment: Interesting. Seems it would be useful for OpenPyXl object as well.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like there are two options:

1. **Leave the `DataFrame` as-is and then use a statement in your template.**

   Currently, you're using the [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) method but it is not called.

   Call the method by adding `()` at the end of `final_data.iterrows`.

   (Also, make sure to close your table header row with `</tr>`.)
2. **Convert the `DataFrame` to HTML and then use an expression in your template.**

   As [@david-sielski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6740411/dawid-sielski) mentions, consider using the [`pandas.DataFrame.to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method.

   Take a look at this example of [How to render Pandas DataFrame as HTML Table?](https://pythonexamples.org/pandas-render-dataframe-as-html-table/)

   Uncomment the `final_df = final_df.to_html()`  line and replace the table with `{{ final_data }}`.

   (Also, make sure to add your styling classes using the `classes` kwarg.)

Check out how to use [developer tools](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/use-devtools) to inspect your HTML if you haven't already.

Comment if you have any questions,

Clay

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried both ways multiple times but it didn't work at all. Now, I simply convert my whole dataframe into numpy array and then pass it to my template to render my table. That way it worked. May be i need deeper understanding in pandas to play with it.

Comment: There is another alternative. Convert DataFrame to dictionary and create a custom template. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom filter in Django to convert your pandas DataFrame to an HTML table using the pandas to_html() method.

Create a new file called filters.py inside a folder called templatetags in your Django app directory.

```
my_app/
  __init__.py
  models.py
  views.py
  etc..
  templatetags/
     __init__.py
     filters.py
  templates/
     index.html
```

In filters.py, define the filter df_to_html as follows:

```
from django import template
import pandas as pd
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name="df_to_html")
def df_to_html(df: pd.DataFrame):
    return mark_safe( df.to_html() )
```

Now you can use the filter in your index.html template file as follows:

```
{% load custom_filters %} 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    ...
   {{ df | df_to_html}}
```

django has documentation about filters here:
[How to create custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option similar to Pablo Guerrero's would be to convert the dataframe to a dictionary with "split" orient.

If index is needed, reset the index before sending df to context:

view.py

```
df = df.reset_index()
context["datatable"] = df.to_dict(orient="split", index=False)
```

template.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for column in datatable.columns %}
      <td>{{ column }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in datatable.data %}
    <tr>
      {% for cell in row %}
      <td>{{ cell }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, if you do not want or cannot reset the index for any reason try this other code instead. This code works with multi-index. The difference in this case is that you need to do "tight" orient, rather than "split". Changing index=False, will hide the index.

view.py

```
context["datatable"] = df.to_dict(orient="tight", index=True)
```

template.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% if datatable.index_names %}
      {% for index_name in datatable.index_names %}
      <td>
        {% if index_name != None %}
        {{index_name}}
        {% endif %}
      </td>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% for column in datatable.columns %}
      <td>{{ column }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in datatable.data %}
    <tr>
      {% if datatable.index %}
      {% for index in datatable.index %}
      {% if forloop.counter0 == forloop.parentloop.counter0 %}
      {% if index|length > 0 %}
      {% for i in index %}
      <td>{{i}}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
      <td>{{index}}</td>
      {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% for cell in row %}
      <td>{{ cell }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```