# Custom HTML table template in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()` method to generate HTML table with custom `data-order` attribute:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>user</th>
      <th>session_length</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>andrew</td>
      <td data-order="125">2h 5m</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>susan</td>
      <td data-order="57">57m</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`data-order` is HTML-5 attribute that allows sorting columns with custom formatting if combining with [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) JavaScript library. Unfortunately, `to_html()` that does not seem to allow custom `<TD>` attributees.

Does pandas use some template (Jinja2?) that I could customize/reuse?

What are my options here?

Minum working example:

```py
import pandas as pd

def format_timedelta(dt):
    components = dt.components
    if components.hours:
        return f"{components.hours}h {components.minutes}m"
    elif components.minutes:
        return f"{components.minutes}m"
    else:
        return f"{components.seconds}s"

df = pd.DataFrame([{
    "user": "adrew",
    "session_length": pd.Timedelta(hours=2, minutes=5)
},
    {
        "user": "susan",
        "session_length": pd.Timedelta(minutes=57)
    }
])
output = df.to_html(
    formatters={
        "session_length": format_timedelta,
    },
    index=False
)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when Styler is used some jinja2 templates are used to render DataFrame, base template are located here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/main/pandas/io/formats/templates .

There are also some examples of template customization in pandas doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Subclassing. It may be useful to use [Styler.from_custom_template](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.from_custom_template.html) method.

In the template code there is available parameter `cell.attributes` which could possibly by used to add custom attributes to cell HTML, but unfortunately it seams not to be exposed via public API. (ref: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/formats/templates/html_table.tpl#L24)

---

One solution could be to use unformatted cell value as a value for `data-order`:

```py
import re
from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler

styler = Styler.from_custom_template(".", "html_table_with_data_order.tpl")(df)

styler.format({"session_length": format_timedelta}) # apply formaters
styler.hide() # hide index

output = styler.to_html(exclude_styles=True)
print(re.sub("\n+", "\n", output))
```

and custom jinja2 template `html_table_with_data_order.tpl` (adapted from [html_table.tpl](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/formats/templates/html_table.tpl)):

```
{%- extends "html_table.tpl" -%}

{% block tr scoped %}
    <tr>
{% if exclude_styles %}
{% for c in r %}{% if c.is_visible != False %}
      <{{c.type}} {{c.attributes}} data-order="{{c.value}}">{{c.display_value}}</{{c.type}}>
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% else %}
{% for c in r %}{% if c.is_visible != False %}
      <{{c.type}} {%- if c.id is defined %} id="T_{{uuid}}_{{c.id}}" {%- endif %} class="{{c.class}}" {{c.attributes}} data-order="{{c.value}}">{{c.display_value}}</{{c.type}}>
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endblock tr %}
```

output:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th >user</th>
      <th >session_length</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td  data-order="adrew">adrew</td>
      <td  data-order="0 days 02:05:00">2h 5m</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  data-order="susan">susan</td>
      <td  data-order="0 days 00:57:00">57m</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like great starting point. The original method `DataFrame.to_html()` does not use Jinja2 templates, but builds HTML purely in Python. Down there it calls [`write_tr()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/formats/html.py#L198) that support custom tags per cell (like data-order) but there's no way to pass it for `<td>` only for `<th>`.

Comment: DataFrame.to_html will not be updated, in fact it will likely be replaced by DataFrame.style.to_html

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simple way of creating a custom HTML template in pandas than using the styler. The trick is converting the dataframe to a dictionary with "thight" orient.

```
datatable = df.to_dict(orient="tight", index=True)
```

If index support is not needed, use this more simple custom template:

```
custom_html_with_no_index_support = """
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for column in datatable.columns %}
      <td>{{ column }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in datatable.data %}
    <tr>
      {% for cell in row %}
      <td>{{ cell }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
"""
```

If index support use this custom template instead:

```
custom_html_with_index_support = """
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% if datatable.index_names %}
      {% for index_name in datatable.index_names %}
      <td>
        {% if index_name != None %}
        {{index_name}}
        {% endif %}
      </td>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% for column in datatable.columns %}
      <td>{{ column }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in datatable.data %}
    {% set outer_loop = loop %}
    <tr>
      {% if datatable.index %}
      {% for index in datatable.index %}
      {% if loop.index0 == outer_loop.index0 %}
      {% if index is mapping %}
      {% for i in index %}
      <td>{{i}}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
      <td>{{index}}</td>
      {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% for cell in row %}
      <td>{{ cell }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
"""
```

To render the custom templates use this code:

```
import jinja2
from IPython.display import display, HTML

environment = jinja2.Environment()

template = environment.from_string(custom_html_with_index_support)
render = template.render(datatable=datatable)
display(HTML(render))
```

If you want to use the shorter custom template with index, you can also reset the index before rendering the table:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

If you are running this code in Django without jinja, please check my answer on this question:
[How can I display pandas DataFrame into Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022914/how-can-i-display-pandas-dataframe-into-django-template/77458456#77458456)